# What are the final step for transporting joomla project from server to computer

Tags: joomla, wamp

I tried to transport a joomla! project from an online server to my local WAMP server. I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SPoYwEPK0VE) tutorial of how to do it and everything went well. I downloaded all the joomla! files from servers public_html folder, then I set up the database (dowloaded .sql file from phpMyAdmin, and exported it to my local wamp sql server), then I set up the configuration.php file as in the tutorial (changed the `$log_path` and 
`$tmp_path`, and everything else stayed the same.) Then it worked fine, localhost loaded all the website, all links worked, it just threw out strickt standart and notice errors, so I just turned them off - in config file `$error_reporting` value changed to `"E_ALL | E_STRICT"`. And then everything worked except the user accounts. I can't log into the joomla/administrator, I can't register to website, and it seems it doesn't store / take the data from database. What should I do to? It clearly has connection to it, because there is no more error about that. What else should I do? Any help would be much appreciated and if there is need for more information, please just ask, I'll give it.

Comment: Have you modified **configuration.php** and **database.php**?

Comment: I modified configuration.php, not database.php. What should I change in database.php and where can I find it?

Comment: Ok, i have found a lot of **database.php** files in my joomla project, but which one is the right one (where should it be located)? And what should I change there?